# flask sessions and forms : trouble displaying user's username when chat page buttons are clicked

Tags: python, flask

I am a beginner programmer working on a simple chatting application in flask using socketio. When a user submits the form on the login page, they are redirected to the chat page where the message "hello [username]" greets them.
However, when they click any other buttons on the chat page, the page refreshes and displays "hello [none]". I think that this problem originates from the flask sessions I have implemented: when a user starts a session and then refreshes the chat page, accessible only by a POST request, it is like they were passing no information in the login in form, which is why the chat page refreshes to "hello {None}".
However, I have no idea on how to fix this issue. I would like the user's username to be saved and be displayed even if they refresh the chat page.
Would I need to save the user's name in a database to achieve this or can this be fixed in another manner? here is the backend:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash, session, redirect
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, send, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
app.static_folder = "static"
app.secret_key = "My_secret_key"
app.config["SECRET KEY"] = "another_secret!"
socketio = SocketIO(app)


@app.route('/')
def login_form():
  return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/chat-page', methods=["POST"])
def chat_page():
  username = request.form.get("user_name")
  session["user"] = username
  return render_template('chat-page.html', Uname=username)


@app.route("/logout")
def logout():
  session.pop("user", None)
  flash("You have been logged out!")
  return redirect("/")


# function to send messages to the entire group
@socketio.on("message")
def handle_message(msg):
  print("message: " + msg)
  send(msg, broadcast=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  socketio.run(app)
```

here is the relevant front-end for the login page:

```
        <form action="/chat-page" class="custom-centered" method="POST">
            <!-- styling the form -->
            <div class="d-inline-flex p-2">
                 <div class="input-group flex-nowrap">
                    <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping">@</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=" Enter a Username" name="user_name" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="addon-wrapping" required>
                 </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end of styling the form -->
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login!</button>
        </form>
```

and here is the relevant front-end of the chat page

```
                <h1> Hello {{Uname}}! </h1>
            </div>
```

Comment: Is that the entire code? It doesn't look like you're using flask.session correctly. Session in flask will persist data in a temporary folder and it's accessible on the client via session cookies. Here is an example on to use session: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-flask-session-in-python-flask/

Comment: thank you this worked! I had followed the instructions from another source, but it could be that it was not the most reliable/out of date.

Comment: could you please post the solution as an answer so that other people can follow-up on it? (would be nice if you could up-vote helpful messages)

Answer (score 1):

the solution that worked for me was
adding the following lines of code to the python file:

```
from flask_session import Session
```

and

```
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(app)
```